# f4p flash video format

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video

What is the difference between .f4v and .f4p flash video formats. 
Only information I have found on Adobe website is that f4p is "Protected media for Flash Player". 
Well my question is: how is it protected? ehat type of protection is that? Ways of encoding? Anything really...

Cheers.

Comment: This isn't really programming related and I have to ask why you need, or want, to know what protection is being used. If you want to play this back within your application then you'll almost certainly need to use the Adobe Flash player plug-in.

Comment: But I want to use flash player. I want to write video player in AS3 (thats why i have put actionscript3 tag) and I need it to be as secure as possible because this is clients requirement. That's why i need to know what type of protection f4p is using? Is it some sort of DRM or what?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here ([PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/protecting_video_fms.pdf)), a white paper on video protection and DRM solutions using Flash Media Server.

Flash player by itself, while it can play f4p which I believe just offers extraction and modification protection, doesn't offer a DRM solution.